# Is it a good practice to reintroduce new generic parameters in C# 7 Local Methods?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, c#-7.0

I was experimenting with C# 7’s new features and especially local methods. I wrote the Linq Where Operator.

I implemented the iterator block as a local method (indeed I read articles saying that local methods are a perfect solution for async methods and iterators).

I'm wondering if there is a difference between those two implementations, and if not which one is the best?

***First implementation:***

Here I introduced new generic type parameter for the local method, new names for the parameters...

```
public static  IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,  Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if(source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if(predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
    return WhereIterator(source,  predicate);

    IEnumerable<TSequence> WhereIterator<TSequence> (IEnumerable<TSequence> localSource,  Func<TSequence, bool>  localPredicat) {
        foreach(TSequence item in localSource) {
            if(localPredicat(item)) {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Second implementation:***

No new generic parameter, no new parameters since the local method can capture the variables of the enclosing method.

```
public static  IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,  Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if(source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if(predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
    return  WhereIterator();

    IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIterator () {
        foreach(TSource item in source) {
            if(predicate(item))
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you even need a WhereIterator at all. You could just not have it, and foreach in the Where method.

Comment: You can check decompiled source [here](https://sharplab.io). Simply write those functions and check result in right window.

Comment: I need eager argument validation :) , If  I don't use the WhereIterator method, argument validation is done lazily . 

That's why I implemented the iterator  as a local method .

Comment: @rokkerboci The LINQ iterators in the framework are implemente the same way except that they don't use local functions, they use private ones because C#7 wasn't around yet. The reason is eager argument validation, you want a null exception happening at the call site, not when the enumeration is actually run; it makes debugging easier and less confusing.

Comment: @InBetween Thank you very much, I actually forgot that that was the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second implementation is better. The main difference is that the second implementation captures its parameters implicitly, freeing you from repeating yourself:

- when specifying parameter types,
- when specifying parameter names, and
- when passing arguments to the function.

Avoiding repetition is a very important programming practice, so you should prefer your second implementation.

Comment: Exactly , We need eager argument validation . This is the main reason why I used local methods in the first place . 

Before I used private static methods to implement the iterator block, but now that we have local methods it's better since it helps to keep the class where I implement Linq extention methods clean from iterators blocks . 

Simply put , it helped me to move the iterator bloc from the class to the Linq operator method since it's used only inside that method .

Comment: But now I'm confused .  My question is simply : should we use implement iterator blocks using the fact that the local method can capture outer variable of the enclosing method , or should we ignore this and introduce new argument type and parameters ?

Comment: @ZackISSER you can do it both ways in this case, so choose one you like more. I personally like first more than a second.

Comment: @ZackISSER Short answer is "second is better;" the answer explains why it is better (DRY principle).

Comment: Ok , I had the same impression at the first place , this being said I shall mark this as an answer .